# "myFunction" is defined but never used & Missing "use strict" statement clash

Tags: javascript, dreamweaver

I was using JavaScript Code in my index.html page. and then I thought to shift all my JavaScript code to .js file. so when I did all the copy-paste thing and moved all my code to .js file. I started getting error in Dreamweaver

error was: Missing "use strict" statement

and so I wrote `"use strict";` on top of my .js file

now I started getting error : Use the function form of "use strict"

so I tried `(function () { "use strict"; //rest of my code })();`

now I have solved all the error related to `"use strict";`

but now I have another error : "myFunction" is defined but never used.

and to solve that I'm using `/*exported myFunction*/`

but that is not working can anyone guide what should I do to remove 2 error I'm getting ?

1. "myFunction" is defined but never used
2. Missing "use strict" statement

should I use `"use strict";` and `/*exported myFunction*/` inside each function of my code onebyone ?

Comment: show your code & check if any function is calling `myFunction`

Comment: this is just a example I used as "myFunction" problem is not in code. It is with jshint jslint

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither of those are errors. They are warnings that Dreamweaver is alerting you to.

1. `"use strict"` is never required, but can be a good best-practice to use in many cases because it can alert you to problems in your code that will silently fail without it.
2. The fact that you have a function, but never call it is also not an error. It's just Dreamweaver telling you about code that seems unnecessary because you are not using that code.

Comment: so does that mean I can ignore both the warnings ? and do not use "use strict" or etc ? I'm very new to JS

Comment: Yes, it does. However, if you do have an expected use for `myFunction`, the fact that it is not being called is something to look into.

Comment: myFunction is just example name I have given here to make people understand my question. in my actual code I'm getting this warnings for 20 functions which are only called when user click on them to open my hidden offcanvas css menu in mobile only. so I think all is perfect with my code. this is just Dreamweaver warnings which I should ignore ? right ?

Comment: Well, yes and no. You *can* ignore them if you know that everything is as it should be. But, they are there to help you understand that this may not be the case. So, no, don't just always ignore the warnings.

Comment: @ArchiPatel: You should always use `'use strict';`; it helps catch errors.  However, there is no need to use the function form.

Comment: @SLaks ok so should I ignore : Use the function form of "use strict". and use 'use strict';

Comment: @ScottMarcus yes got it. basically my website is totally new and so all the function which I have used are needed. only thing is that functions are called only when USER clicks on button. so i guess they are all perfect anyways thx

Comment: @ArchiPatel Again, `"use strict"` is generally a best-practice, but not required. In some cases, using `"use strict"` can cause code to stop working. I would recommend not using it until you understand what it does.

Comment: @ScottMarcus maybe ur right I should avoid it as of now but in future maybe I will use it tx